# Is There Another Way to (Poetically) Say "Sie ist schön?"

Tags: word-choice

In one of my translations, I used: "[Deine Mutter] hat Schönheit. The original is a line in [Gershwin's Summertime](http://www.lyricsmode.com/lyrics/g/george_gershwin/summertime.html).

My translation was:

> Sommerzeit, und das Leben ist leicht.
>   Fische beissen, wenn der Baumwoll aufsteigt.
>   Dein Vater ist reich, DEINE MUTTER HAT SCHöENHEIT.
>   Ach, Kindlein sei schweigsam, du muss nicht weinen.

Comment: Aren't fish jumping? And the cotton is high. I always thought it to mean 'Die Fische hüpfen (springen), und die Baumwolle blüht/steht in Blüte.' `Kindlein` for `baby` is wrong - Kindlein isn't a Kosewort for the beloved one. `Liebstes`, maybe?

Comment: @user_unknown "Summertime" is a lullaby, so baby actually means "Kindlein".

Comment: "beißen" is a very non-poetic word. If "the fish are jumping" really means that you can catch fish easily (instead of "the Fish are jumping out of the water", rather write something like "Leicht fängt man Fisch und die Baumwolle blüht". Also, "schweigsam" means rather "close-mouthed" than "quiet". Splattne's translation is fine, although "pst" looks a bit strange. "Sch" doesn't look better, though, so maybe use "still"?

Comment: @user @splattne Original lyrics has "hush, little baby" which makes it obvious (and with the following "don't you cry" even more so) that the "audience" is, in fact, a baby.

Comment: @jae, @splattne: Yes, I accept the song to be a lullaby (while I know adult persons, who have reason to cry, and do so), however, my comment that "Kindlein" is wrong is wrong - I admit it! But the fish still don't bite, but jump, and 'die Baumwolle steigt' nicht, wie einst aus den Nebeln der Mond, da bleibe ich stur. :)

Comment: Aus den Nebeln?  Ich kenne nur aus den Wiesen, und wer da rausstieg war der weisse Neger Wumbaba.  ;-)

Comment: "die Baumwolle blüht" ist natürlich Unsinn. Die blüht im späten Frühling - "high" ist sie dann, wenn die Samenkapseln im Sommer (und um den geht's ja) reif sind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Hat Schönheit" is theoretically possible, but isn't generally used. It sounds a bit abstract ("has beauty"), you would usually use it in combination with an adjective (like "hat eine besondere Schönheit").

How about **"Deine Mutter ist eine Schönheit"** instead? "Your mother is a beauty."

To me, "good-lookin'" is a bit different from "beautiful", though - it has a trace of a hint of a sexual connotation for which "ist eine hübsche" might be a more fitting translation.

A couple of other things in your text that I would do differently:

> Fische beissen, wenn der Baumwoll aufsteigt.

- Fische beissen **an** (this is specific to biting in a hunting/fishing context)
- Using "wenn" is difficult here: it suggests a correlation between fish biting and cotton being high - maybe use "und" like in the original?
- "Die Baumwolle" is feminine
- I wouldn't use "aufsteigen" to depict a plant's growth. One thing that comes to mind that should work in a gardening/agricultural context is "hoch stehen", as in "Die Baumwolle steht hoch".
- "schweigsam" refers to the character trait of being a quiet child. One (but not the only) poetic version of "hush!" would be "Still, mein Kind!"

Comment: For poetic purposes, "good-looking" and beautiful are similar. No need to put too fine a point on these things. Poetically, I was trying to emphasize the ei, hence Sommerzeit, leicht, beissen, aufsteigen, Schönheit. schweigsam, usw.

Answer (score 7):

The song *Summertime* is a **lullaby**, so you should consider that when you're translating it. I tried to write the complete lyrics in German just to unterstand the mood:

> Sommerzeit,
>   Und das Leben ist einfach.
>   Fische springen,
>   Die Baumwolle steht in voller Blüte.
>
> Oh, dein Papa ist reich
>   **Und deine Mama sieht gut aus.**
>   Also, pst, kleines Baby,
>   Weine nicht!
>
> An einem dieser Morgen
>   Wirst du singend aufstehen
>   Dann wirst du deine Flügel ausbreiten
>   Und in den Himmel aufsteigen.
>
> Aber bis zu jenem Morgen
>   Gibt's nichts, das dir schaden kann,
>   Wenn Papa und Mama
>   Bei dir sind.
>
> Sommerzeit,
>   Und das Leben ist einfach.
>   Fische springen,
>   Und die Baumwolle steht hoch.
>
> Oh, dein Papa ist reich
>   Und deine Mama sieht gut aus
>   Also, psst, kleines Baby
>   Weine nicht!

Comment: I never realized this was a lullaby, so this completely changed my perception of this wonderful song - for the first time, I think I really get it. Thanks for that!

Comment: This is very nice. The only thing I don't entirely agree with is the use of "so" - "also" wäre besser, oder?

Comment: Kann man ausschließen, dass 'Cotton is high' für 'blühen' steht, oder für 'reich an Frucht'? 'Steht hoch' klingt für mich sehr geknittelt.

Comment: @pekka @user_unknown danke für die Anregungen. Ich glaube, es passt am besten: *Die Baumwolle steht in voller Blüte.*

Comment: @splattne: einige zusätzliche Anregungen, wo wir gerade dabei sind (auch wenn's ja über den Fokus der Frage weit hinausgeht - ignore at wish): *Sommerzeit* ruft meiner Erfahrung nach eher Gedanken an die Zeitumstellung hervor. Vielleicht fährt man hier mit "Es ist Sommer" o.ä. besser? *Einfaches Leben* klingt für mich mehr nach Armut/Bauernromantik als nach der "Leichtigkeit des Lebens", die wahrscheinlich gemeint ist. *Deine Mutter sieht gut aus* hat für mich einen flacheren/oberflächlicheren Klang als "Deine Mutter ist schön", und man würde es so nicht unbedingt einem Kind vorsingen...

Comment: @Jan Ich glaube *Deine Mutter sieht gut aus* ist hier durchaus angebracht, weil es dem Kind eine "heile Welt" vermitteln soll: Papa ist reich, Mutter sieht gut aus. (nicht meine Geschlechterrollenwahl übrigens) :)

Comment: @splattne meine Bedenken waren hier eher, dass *deine Mutter sieht gut aus* eher die äußerlichen Reize einer Frau auf eine Art beschreibt, wie es Erwachsene (und auch eher Männer) untereinander tun würden, nicht unbedingt Kinder. Es ist m.E. konkreter im Hinblick auf die mitschwingenden Intentionen als "deine Mutter ist schön/eine schöne Frau". Und ja, das mit der Rollenwahl geht mir ähnlich ;-)

Comment: @Jan "deine Mutter sieht gut aus" trifft den Ton des Originals besser als "Deine Mutter ist schön".  Es soll ja nicht unbedingt Kindersprache sein (jedenfalls ist "your mamma's good lookin'" auch im Englischen keine Kindersprache, sondern hat genau diesen von die erwähnten Unterton)

Comment: @jae: jo, das ist wahr - guter Punkt. Das bedeutet also, wir haben bereits im Original die Diskrepanz zwischen Kinderlied und "erwachsenem" Unterton...

Answer (score 2):

```
Deine Mutter sieht schön aus.
Deine Mutter schaut gut aus.
Deine Mutter ist hübsch.
Deine Mutter ist schön.
```

Eins davon würde ich sagen. Pekka scheint Janis Joplin nicht zu kennen. Pardon - Gershwin. Google: Summertime lyrics.

Comment: Hat Janis Joplin den Text mal in Deutsch gesungen?

Comment: Nicht dass ich wüßte, aber die Rückübertragung "Your mother is a beauty." statt `your mum 's good looking` deutete darauf hin, wie die Akzeptanz beißender Fische (fish are jumping, and the cotton is high).

Comment: ah, okay. Ich kenne den Text nicht auswendig, das stimmt :) "schön" wasn't my idea though, and I explicitly suggest a translation that fits "good-lookin'" better